# C# auto fit to any screen resolution

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a small project using MS Visual Studio C# 2010.

In my MainFormDesigner.cs file I have the following code. All it does is load a web page from my server. I need the app to fill the display which is 1080 x 1920. But when I save and build the app some the the sizes default to the resolution of the screen I am working on.

Is there a way to automatically size the app to fit the resoltion of any screen the app runs on.

```
namespace Impa_Browser
{
partial class MainForm
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.browser = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
        this.connectLbl = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // browser
        // 
        this.browser.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.browser.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(0);
        this.browser.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
        this.browser.Name = "browser";
        this.browser.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
        this.browser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1080, 1920); // THIS IS THE RESOLUTION OF THE  DISPLAY THE APP WILL RUN ON
        this.browser.TabIndex = 0;
        this.browser.Url = new System.Uri("example.com", System.UriKind.Absolute);
        this.browser.DocumentCompleted += new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(this.browser_DocumentCompleted);
        // 
        // connectLbl
        // 
        this.connectLbl.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.connectLbl.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 48F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(204)));
        this.connectLbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.connectLbl.Name = "connectLbl";
        this.connectLbl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1080, 1092); // THIS KEEPS CHANGING TO THE RESOLUTION OF THE SCREEN I AM WORKING ON
        this.connectLbl.TabIndex = 1;
        this.connectLbl.Text = " Trying to connect ...[20] Please check your Internet router";
        this.connectLbl.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
        // 
        // MainForm
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1080, 1092); // THIS KEEPS CHANGING TO THE RESOLUTION OF THE SCREEN I AM WORKING ON
        this.Controls.Add(this.browser);
        this.Controls.Add(this.connectLbl);
        this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.Name = "MainForm";
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Impa";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.MainForm_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser browser;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label connectLbl;
}
}
```

Many thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: You shouldn't be editing the MainFormDesigner.cs, designer files are exactly that, for the designer to manage. Make your changes in the normal code file instead.

Comment: Have you tried setting the window state of the form to maximized?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WinForms you can set the WindowState to [FormWindowState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formwindowstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Maximized like this.

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

For WPF user [WindowsState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate(v=vs.110).aspx) Maximized

```
this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, in my code where would I insert "this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;"

Comment: As Heiko Mueller suggested in the second answer you can achieve this in different ways. The simplest way would be, to set the Property WindowState of your main windows in the Designer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions to achive this goal:

1) Simply change the **WindowState** property in the Designer to **Maximized**.

2) If you don't wanna change this property you can do this in code - for example in the **Load** Event of your form like this:

```
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

3) Overwrite the **OnLoad** method of your form like this:

```
protected override OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
     base.OnLoad(e);
     this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
```

4) If there is a good reason to not work with WindowState you can use the **Screen**class object for screen where your form is displayed. For example like this:

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnShown(e);

    // get the current screen
    Screen screen = Screen.FromControl(this);

    // set Location and Size of your form to fit in the WorkingArea
    Location = new Point(screen.WorkingArea.Left, screen.WorkingArea.Top);
    Size = new Size(screen.WorkingArea.Width, screen.WorkingArea.Height);
}
```